# How do I create a dynamic equals query using Apache Camel and MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-camel

I'd like to query a MongoDB collection dynamically from an Apache Camel route. The [Apache Camel docs show how to query a collection using a `constant` value](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/mongodb-component.html#_findonebyquery):

```
from("direct:findOneByQuery")
    .setHeader(MongoDbConstants.CRITERIA, Filters.eq("name", "Raul Kripalani"))
    .to("mongodb:myDb?database=flights&collection=tickets&operation=findOneByQuery")
    .to("mock:resultFindOneByQuery");
```

And while I'm sure that's useful to some folks, I was trying to query a collection with a dynamically generated value, using an Exchange header for instance. How do you do that?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, that statement above won't compile. It was pointed out to me in another question that there's an error in current Apache Camel MongoDB documentation and that the `setHeader` line above should read:

```
.setHeader(MongoDbConstants.CRITERIA, constant(Filters.eq("name", "Raul Kripalani"))
```

The way I ended up doing this was by creating an anonomyous `Expression`:

```
import com.mongodb.client.model.Filters;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import org.bson.conversions.Bson;

@Component
public class NotifyClientRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    public static final String NOTIFY_CLIENT_URI = "direct:notifyClient";

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

      from(NOTIFY_CLIENT_URI)
        .log("Determining which client gets the deletion request next for DR request '${header.drRequestId}'.")
        .setHeader(MongoDbConstants.CRITERIA, new Expression() {
            @Override
            public <T> T evaluate(Exchange exchange, Class<T> type) {
                String drRequestId = exchange.getIn().getHeader("drRequestId", String.class);

                Bson equalsClause = Filters.eq("drRequestId", drRequestId);

                // Alternatively:
                // Bson equalsClause = new BasicDBObject("drRequestId", new BasicDBObject("$eq", drRequestId));

                return exchange.getContext().getTypeConverter().convertTo(type, equalsClause);
            };
        })
        .to("mongodb:mongoClient?database=mydb&collection=mycollection&operation=findOneByQuery")
        .log("Query returned: '${body}'");
    }
}
```

Additional note: I didn't come up with that return statement in the `Expression`. I was running into type errors, and so I looked at what another Apache Camel `Expression` implementations included in the Camel libraries were returning, and I found that return clause.