# Query MongoDB with dynamic selector in Camel

Tags: mongodb, apache-camel

I found a solution here: [How do I create a dynamic equals query using Apache Camel and MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64547706/how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-equals-query-using-apache-camel-and-mongodb)

But this looks like a lot of work. Doesn't Camel have a simpler way to pass values to a MongoDB query? I wish we could just pass the actual find({}) language that Mongo uses.

Here is what I have working, with some logging showing what it's doing:

```
.setHeader(MongoDbConstants.CRITERIA, new Expression() {
    @Override
    public <T> T evaluate(Exchange exchange, Class<T> type) {
        Long drRequestId = exchange.getIn().getHeader("orderid", Long.class);

        Bson equalsClause = Filters.eq("id", drRequestId);



        return exchange.getContext().getTypeConverter().convertTo(type, equalsClause);
    };
})
.log(MongoDbConstants.CRITERIA)
.log("${headers.CamelMongoDbCriteria}")
.to("mongodb:mongo?database={{spring.data.mongodb.database}}&collection=ftx_orders&operation=findOneByQuery")
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try with `${body.id}`?

Also, you can also send it in header, setting using

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader("id","value");
```

and then using the same way you mentioned above.

```
.setHeader(MongoDbConstants.CRITERIA, constant(Filters.eq("name", simple("${header.id}"))))
```

Comment: I made a type error in the OP. Yeah, I've tried ${body.id} but I think that will try to call the method id on an object in the body.

Comment: And when I use simple() inside Filter.equ() I get the error: org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class org.apache.camel.builder.SimpleBuilder